# Не работает код по запрету звука через настройки?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-shared-preferences, android-mediaplayer

Делаю приложение и надо чтобы в настройках можно было убрать звук, делаю сохранение данных через sharedPreferences, но switch не сохраняет положение(checked, nonchecked) и звук всё равно идёт. Вот код из SettingsActivity в методе onCreate() :

```
  cb_sound_settings = findViewById(R.id.cb_settings_sounds);
  if (cb_sound_settings.isChecked()) {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Sounds", true);
        editor.apply();
    } else {
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Sounds", false);
        editor.apply();
    }

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Sounds", true)) {
        cb_sound_settings.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cb_sound_settings.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Xml код из layout_settings.xml:

```
     <Switch
    android:id="@+id/cb_settings_sounds"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGray"
    android:checked="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/settings_sounds"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

И код из MainActivity, где должен был быть запрет на звук:

```
  public void showSuccessfulToastVerb () {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's not a irregular verb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    successfulSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.successful);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Sounds", true)) {
        successfulSound.start();
    }
}
```

Помогите пж, таже фигня была когда пытался запретить анимацию (

Comment: вы можете обходиться без if-else, например `cb_sound_settings.setChecked( sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Sounds", true) )` и `editor.putBoolean("Sounds",  cb_sound_settings.isChecked() )`;

Comment: @zRrr Спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде вы не обрабатываете нажатие на `Switch`. Нужно делать так:

```
cb_sound_settings.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("Sounds", isChecked).apply();
    } 
});

cb_sound_settings.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Sounds",ваше_значение_по_умолчанию));
```

Comment: откуда там взялось isChecked в методе у меня такого нету, или это тот же boolean b?

Comment: @DanilOchagov из `public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)`